# SWLT short dumps during check of SCI inspection

Tags: abap

I use [SWLT tool](https://help.sap.com/viewer/a24970c68fcf4770a64bf9a78e3719e2/7.4.19/en-US/713ff185b9b347aaacbe3ada28d4fa72.html) to check for inefficient SQL statements and experience a dump every time I start it by SCI inspection created with `DEFAULT` check variant. No matter which input object I pass to it.

[image]

[image]

But if I choose `PERFORMANCE_DB` variant all goes fine during SWLT run.

Yes, I aware that in recommendations they say that this variant is recommended

[image]

however, in my opinion it shouldn't throw such ugly dump anyway.

Anybody encountered such an error? Is it release-dependent and was fixed already in higher releases? I am on ABAP 750 SP00.

Comment: It looks like a database integrity error. Having `<asx:abap ...` in a data cluster is theoretically impossible and cannot be read. A data cluster starts with bytes FF, 01 to 06, 01 or 02, 01 or 02, etc. You have to analyze why this table (which one?) has this wrong value, eventually delete it, but be careful! It's impossible to help more on that problem.

Comment: but what is the name of corrupted cluster? I cannot find it in dump description

Comment: I can answer only if you attach the whole short dump... (by looking at the concerned ABAP statement and the values of the variables used)

Comment: dump occurs in method `GET_DETAIL_SINGLE` of class `CL_CI_TEST_ROOT` as seen from screenshots, [in line 13](https://imgur.com/a/NSeldzC), the contents of the dynamic `params` [is following](https://imgur.com/Qybj5mw). I don't see any cluster here, it imports data from data buffer `p_detail_packed` and it is an XSTRING attribute

Comment: Hmmm I thought it would be a simple `IMPORT ... FROM DATABASE ...` but in your case, you have to debug to find out where `p_detail_packed` comes from... This is something I can't do, sorry! (if you had provided the full short dump, the call stack and so on, I would probably have had a better chance to locate the origin of the issue)